# Php- Object COM doesnt work

Tags: php

I'm trying to use a DLL in php but when I try to print my object... it says "Undefined variable" or "LoadDefinitionObject doesn't support this property or method". Can somebody tell me how ca I fix this bug? My code is this:

```
$obj = new COM("dlltest.otherfunction") or Die ("Did not connect");
var_dump($obj);
```

Comment: I think die needs to be lower case and have the parenthesis connected to it.

Comment: Yes, change `Die ("Did not connect");` to `die("Did not connect");`

Comment: I changed it but it still does not work